# How to use string type annotations to avoid importing un-needed class definitions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have found many questions about recursive-forward declarations (i.e. the problem that `typing.Self` solves), but I have a different question.

To avoid circular dependence between modules, I would like to forward declare some type annotations in the following way.

```
# note: no import of MyOtherClass here

@dataclass
MyClass:
    value: 'MyOtherClass'|None = None

# note: no definition of class MyOtherClass later in this module
```

`'MyOtherClass'|None` gives an error and I don't know how to fix it.

Additionally, I would like to know, is it legal to deploy a string type hint without providing a definition of the type in the same module?

My mental model is C++, where you forward declare classes whenever you don't need a definition of the type.

Comment: Without importing the module, it's anyone's guess _which_ `MyOtherClass` is meant…